# How can I send a variable from an embedded SVG to the HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I embedded a SVG into a HTML document using this code

```
<embed src="circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

In the SVG file, I got a script block like this

```
<svg onload="myFunction()">
<script  type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
    function myFunction() {
        var sum;
        sum = 5 + 3;
    }
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

How can I get the variable 'sum' from the SVG in the HTML document?
(Note: The scripting in the SVG is a lot more complex than a simple sum, but I didn't want to overload this question with code)

Comment: The more general question I think is, what is the relationship of the execution context of JavaScript in SVG imported via an `<embed>` tag to the JavaScript environment of the containing page?  I don't know the answer, but I can think of experiments ... for example, can the code in the SVG see the `window` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can define javascript functions in SVG and call them (at least externally). However, you can probably achieve what you want by defining the function in the HTML file instead of in the SVG. For instance, if you want to count all rectangles in a given SVG, you can use a code as follows:

```
<embed id="mySVG" src="circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload="countRectangles();"/>
<script>
  function countRectangles()
    {
      var svg = document.getElementById("mySVG").getSVGDocument();
      var allRectangles = svg.getElementsByTagName("rect");

      var result = allRectangles.length
      alert(result);
      return result;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I tries this code but I get this error: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/.../image.svg from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/.../test.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: Aha. I solved the error. I just ran the html document from localhost and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you would do exactly as if the <embed> was an <iframe> and the document inside it was an HTML document.

You can pass data e.g via [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage), or by using global variables or functions on the corresponding window object.

in the svg:

```
function foo() {
  var parentWindow = window.parent;
  parentWindow.someGlobalVar = 47;
}
```

Then you can read the `someGlobalVar` variable in the html main document. You can also call functions, as in [this example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/from-svg-to-parent-html-script.html).

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it. I tried it but I get this error `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/.../testSVG.html from frame with URL file:///C:/Users/.../world_test.svg. Domains, protocols and ports must match.`

Comment: Yes, this happens when you run it locally (in webkit), any difference if you serve it off somewhere where the domain for both documents are the same?

Comment: Aha. I solved the error. I just ran the html document from localhost and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is a work arround. I don't know how old this Question was, but someone will get use of it.

---

In the SVG file.

```
<svg onload="myFunction()">
<script  type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
    function myFunction() {
        var sum;
        sum = 5 + 3;
    }
    if(window.parent.svgLoaded) window.parent.svgLoaded(this);
]]>
</script>
</svg>
```

---

on the embeded HTML file.

```
<script>
    var svgScript;
    function svgLoaded(script){
        alert("gotcha!")
        svgScript = script;
    }
    function onPlayPause(){
        svgScript.myFunction();
    }
</script>
```

It works.